# display content containing html tags from database using php

Tags: php, html, sql

Table name : Post, column name : content
say, below data along with the html tag and style is stored in content column

```
<h1 style="color:red">test</h1>
```

I'm using below php code to display it

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT content FROM post where id = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['content'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    <?php
  }
}
else {
echo "0 rasdesults";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

expectation : test in red color but 
output : only  "test"

Comment: what is the value of `$queryname`? it's a string, right?

Comment: now you went and edited that out. You're making this post more unclear.

Comment: $queryname was part of my query, which can be ignored here. hence edited the sql query. BTW , since the output is being generated, m guessing that the query is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace you echo syntaxt

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['content'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

with below line

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['content']);?>
```

Hope this will help you!
Thanks & regards.
Shishil Patel